# How to order an array of objects according to different properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, topological-sort

I need to order an array where the elements are objects. I want to fill up a dropdown in a specific order

```
[{ id: 1, name: "Country", parent: null, level: 0 }, 
{ id: 48, name: "Village1", parent: 16, level: 2 }, 
{ id: 17, name: "City1", parent: 1, level: 1 }, 
{ id: 15, name: "Village4", parent: 16, level: 2 }, 
{ id: 61, name: "City2", parent: 1, level: 1 }, 
{ id: 16, name: "City3", parent: 1, level: 1 }, 
{ id: 85, name: "City6", parent: 1, level: 1 }, 
{ id: 31, name: "Village2", parent: 77, level: 2 }, 
{ id: 76, name: "City4", parent: 1, level: 1 }, 
{ id: 77, name: "City5", parent: 1, level: 1 }, 
{ id: 79, name: "Village3", parent: 77, level: 2 }]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to to get a dropdown where first appear the Country (parent null), then its children, but immediately, if those children have also children, they should appear down below, kind of:
- Country
- City1
- City2
- City3
- Village1
- Village2
- City4
. . .
And so on..

Anyone can give me a hand? I am really struggling here...

Comment: What is logic or sorting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create a tree, following is half answer, I think its help you.

```js
let arrOfObjectData = [{ id: 1, name: "Country", parent: null, level: 0 },
{ id: 48, name: "Village1", parent: 16, level: 2 },
{ id: 17, name: "City1", parent: 1, level: 1 },
{ id: 15, name: "Village4", parent: 16, level: 2 },
{ id: 61, name: "City2", parent: 1, level: 1 },
{ id: 16, name: "City3", parent: 1, level: 1 },
{ id: 85, name: "City6", parent: 1, level: 1 },
{ id: 31, name: "Village2", parent: 77, level: 2 },
{ id: 76, name: "City4", parent: 1, level: 1 },
{ id: 77, name: "City5", parent: 1, level: 1 },
{ id: 79, name: "Village3", parent: 77, level: 2 }];

let allParent = arrOfObjectData.filter((ele) => ele.parent == 1);
let treeArrOfObject = [];
allParent.forEach(element => {
 let findChild = arrOfObjectData.filter((elm) => elm.parent == element.id);
 treeArrOfObject.push({ parent: findChild, children: findChild });
});
console.log(treeArrOfObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first add all the children into a property of their parent.

```
[
  {
    id: 1, 
    name: "Country", 
    children:[{id: 17, name: "Village1", parent: 1, level: 1}]
  },    
  {
    id: 2, 
    name: "Country2", 
    children:[{id: 19, name: "Village2", parent: 2, level: 1}]
  },    
]
```

Then loop through the parents, output them & nest a loop going through each parent's children and outputting them

```
parents.forEach((parent) => {
  //output parent
  parent.children.forEach((child) => {
  //output child
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

That should do it:

```
let finalArray = [];
originalArray.map(x => {
   if(x.name === 'Country') {finalArray[0] = x}
   if(x.name === 'City1') {finalArray[1] = x}
   if(x.name === 'City2') {finalArray[2] = x}
   if(x.name === 'City3') {finalArray[3] = x}
   if(x.name === 'Village1') {finalArray[4] = x}
   if(x.name === 'Village2') {finalArray[5] = x}
   if(x.name === 'City4') {finalArray[6] = x}
 })
```